# Please remove question 363427

Tags: support, status-declined

Please remove my question: [Migrate profiles from x86 to x64 Vista?](https://serverfault.com/q/363427/98093)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, your question has become part of the community knowledge base.
It belongs to the community now and is no longer your choice to delete.

Please see the blog entry [Adventures in Declustionism](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/) for more insight as to why the community "takes ownership" of a Question/Answers. Moderators do not decide when a Question gets turned over, the community does by voting. This is why you no longer have the option to delete the Question yourself.

Comment: How do you decide what’s part of the knowledge base and what isn’t?

Comment: I don't. If it wasn't, you'd be able to delete it. =]

Comment: So why was it closed?

Comment: 5 People thought it should be closed. More descriptively, it's pretty clear you aren't a system administrator and the question is about a home computer, which is off-topic per the [faq].